# How many values of $\chi$ are there?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I have studied Analytic number theory with Apostol's text book

In page 142, proof of Theorem 6.19, the following is written:

> Since Dirichlet Character $\chi$ is real-valued the only possible values for $\chi$(n) are 0 , 1 and -1.

But in the table modulus 5, $\chi_{3}(2) = i$

Is the book wrong ?

Comment: I don't have the book in front of me, but presumably Apostol was referring to a specific Dirichlet character when he said that it was real-valued. In general, Dirichlet characters will not be real-valued.

Comment: @carmichael561 i understood thank you!

Comment: there are $\phi(q)$ characters modulo $q$, and only two of them are real-valued : the principal character $\chi(n) = 1_{gcd(n,q) = 1}$, and the quadratic character $\chi(n) = \left( \frac{n}{q} \right)$ (the Jacobi symbol)

Answer (score 1):

The statement of Theorem 6.19 is for **any real-valued character**. But a general Dirichlet character is complex-valued. Thus there is no conflict between these statements in the book.